# Can the QWidget mainwindow .h be included in its child widget class?

Tags: qt

I put a widget named `myWiget` in QMainWindow. The myWidget is promoted to a class named `PaintImage` (`PaintImage *myWidget`). Here what I am going to do is to draw image in the sub-widget `myWidget` by PaintImage in which `painter` method is called.

In the `PaintImage.h`, I have `#include "mainwindow.h"` and declare `MainWindow *main`. I use the pointer `main` to access some variables of interest defined there, e.g.:

```
int w = ui->myWidget->geometry().width();
int h = ui->myWidget->geometry().height();
```

Then in `paintimage.cpp`:

```
PaintImage::PaintImage(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    //these lines of codes cause the problem!
    int w = main->w; 
    int h = main->h; 
    .......
}

void PaintImage::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /*event*/)
{
   //QPainter painter is called inside
}
```

Compiling the codes shows that:

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
The process was ended forcefully.
```

What causes the problem? Cannot I access the `MainWindow` members from inside `PaintImage`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show a minimal compilable sample (including your `main()`). What do you see when you debug your app step by step?

Comment: Too many questions appears when reading the post. Why not use `#include "mainwindow.h"` in PaintImage.cpp only, combined with forward declaration? Why not use `qobject_cast` with `parent` pointer? Why not to get all geomery, required for painting from the custom widget itself? What is "main" pointer?